# "Schiffen gehen" -- regionale Bedeutung?

Tags: meaning, regional

Ich kenne den Ausdruck "*schiffen gehen*" nur im Zusammenhang mit Stuhlgang, höre ihn aber gelegentlich im Sinne von Wasserlassen. Laut google scheint die letztere Bedeutung verbreitet zu sein.

Gibt es da eventuell regionale Unterschiede, oder kenne ich den Ausdruck falsch?

Comment: Ich kenne ihn von hier (Unterfranken) auch als "Wasserlassen". Du solltest noch ergänzen, woher in Deutschland (?) du kommst.

Comment: ich kenne ihn ausschliesslich in der Bedeutung "Wasserlassen". "Es schifft" hat hier (BW) die Bedeutung "es regnet".

Comment: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachttopf
Den ersten Satz interpretierend, würde es wohl für den Stuhlgang an sich gelten; ich denke aber mal, dass es hier und da 'uminterpretiert' wurde.

Comment: @Em1: Der WP-Artikel enthält keine online überprüfbaren Belege.  Und der Satz mit "schiffen gehen" bezieht sich wohl auf schweizer Benutzung.  Dazu kann ich nichts sagen.  Aber ich weiss sicher, wie meine Vorkommentatoren, dass ich "schiffen gehen" immer nur ausschliesslich in der Bedeutung "Wasser lassen" gehört habe.  In Süddeutschland (Nordbaden) jedenfalls.

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard Bei uns im Rheinland ist das auch so.

Comment: @Em1 In einen Nachttopf kann man wunderbar wasserlassen. Ich kann aus der Herkunft des Verbs "schiffen" vom der Bezeichnung "Schiff" für den Nachttopf nicht entnehmen, dass es hier unbedingt um Stuhlgang gehen muss. "Schiff" ist auch eine Bezeichnung für flache Trinkgefäße oder das Gefäß, in dem das Bier im Brauhaus abkühlt ("Kühlschiff"). (Quelle: Grimms WB) Es ist wahrscheinlich, dass der Nachttopf nach FLÜSSIGKEITSENTHALTENDEN Gefäßen benannt ist, und schiffen sich also auf die Ausscheidung einer Flüssigkeit bezieht. In Oberschwaben bedeutet "schiffen" ausschließlich urinieren.

Comment: Kenne _schiffen gehen_ aus dem Rheinland nur für pinkeln. War damals in der Schulzeit weit verbreitet.

Comment: In Sachsen auch nur mit der Bedeutung _Wasserlassen_.

Answer (score 17):

Ich kenne ihn ehrlich gesagt nur in der Bedeutung "Wasserlassen". Vielleicht ist das aber keine regionale, sondern eher eine Generationsfrage? Zumindest kenne ich viele Leute in meinem Alter aus unterschiedlichsten Regionen, die mir zustimmen würden, und auch einige Filme mit der Zielgruppe "junge Leute", die tatsächlich das Wort schiffen in dem Zusammenhang benutzen.

Comment: In den 20ern seiend, würde ich wohl auch eher zu der jüngeren Generation zählen, oder? Meine Sprachlichen Wurzeln liegen in Nordrhein-Westfalen/Niedersachsen. Ich hatte mich halt nur gefragt ob ich das Wort einfach nur falsch kenne -- dem scheint ja wohl so zu sein.

Answer (score 11):

Bin aus dem westlichen Norden Deutschlands und das Wort *schiffen* hat hier nicht im geringsten etwas mit Stuhlgang zutun. Es bedeutet urinieren und ist nicht unbedingt derb. Derb ist der Ausdruck *pissen*.

*Schiffen* ist hier aber auch ein Ausdruck für regnen. Wird gesagt, wenn der Regen einem nicht grad willkommen ist.

Answer (score 5):

Lediglich in der Umgangssprache sagt man "Ich gehe schiffen" oder "Ich gehe eine Stange Wasser parken" nur wenn man ausdrücken möchte, dass ein (hochdeutsch) kurzer Besuch der Toilette ansteht oder dass man austreten muß. Im Krankenhaus wird dann eher vom "Wasser lassen" gesprochen -- im Gegensatz zum Stuhlgang, der die lange Sitzung auf der Toilette bezeichnet und sich auf die festen Ausscheidungen bezieht.

Früher wurde umgangssprachlich statt "ich gehe schiffen" auch "ich gehe seichen" gesagt, das eine Spur schlimmer im Ausdruck war. Das habe ich aber schon länger nicht mehr gehört. Laut Hubert Schölnast ist "[soachn](http://www.ostarrichi.org/woerterbuch.html?wort=7881)" ein vulgärer Dialektausdruck aus dem Osten der Steiermark für "urinieren".

Entsprechend waren dann "Es schifft" oder "Es seicht" umgangssprachliche Ausdrücke für "Es regnet", wobei von der Tendenz her "Es seicht" einen stärkeren Regen verdeutlichte.

Umgangssprachlich kann man auch noch "pissen" sagen, das "pinkeln" entspricht.

Diese Wortwahl ist mir von Bayern, Baden-Württemberg und Österreich bekannt.

Speziell aus Bayern kenne ich noch "[brunzen](http://www.oesterreichisch.net/oesterreich-105-brunzen.html?letter=B)" (laut Hubert auch in Wien bekannt). Dieses Wort findet sich sogar in dem Lied "Die Rittersleut" von Truck Stop, im Original von Karl Valentin (bayrischer Komiker). Es ist ein Dialektwort, das "pinkeln" bedeutet und meiner Einschätzung nach nicht zur vulgären Sprache gehört.

Comment: "seuchen" kenne ich nicht, aber "soach'n". Das ist ein vulgärer Dialektausdruck aus dem Osten der Steiermark für urinieren. Ähnlich vulgär, wenn auch weiter verbreitet (zumindest meiner Wahrnehmung nach) ist auch "brunzen", das man im Gegensatz zu "soach'n" auch in Wien kennt.
"Schiffen" kenne ich auch nur als Vulgärausdruck für "urinieren". Als Bezeichnung für den Stuhlgang ist mir das nicht bekannt.

Comment: Ob "seichen" wirklich vulgär ist, oder nur veraltet?

Comment: „soicha” gibts auch im Schwäbischen, ebenfalls sowohl für Wasser lassen wie auch für starken Regenfall verwendet.

Comment: "soachn" ist auch in Bayern weitverbreitet, zumindest in Ober- und Niederbayern.

Comment: Und nein, "seichen" ist eher veraltet als vulgär. Im Schwäbischen gibt es die nette Geschichte der durchaus honoriigen Dame, die in Stuttgart im Krankenhaus war und sagte: "I komm aus Schönaich und bring mein Saich"

Comment: 'Umgangssprachlich kann man auch noch "pissen" sagen, das "pinkeln" entspricht.' - was meinst du mit "entspricht"? Ich empfinde "pissen" schon als bedeutend derber als "pinkeln"; in der Tat würde ich "pinkeln" sogar als geeigneten Ausdruck im Kontakt mit Kindern ansehen, "pissen" aber auf keinen Fall.

Comment: Davon unabhängig ist der Ausdruck "Es pisst." natürlich auch für Regen gängig, vermutlich ungefähr gleichbedutend mit dem beschriebenen "Es seicht." (Vielleicht klanglich bedingt assoziiere ich persönlich "Es pisst." aber eher mit einem starken, prasselnden Regen, während ich bei "Es seicht." eher an "weichere" Regentropfen denken muss, die einen dennoch komplett einnässen.)

Answer (score 4):

Ich spreche für Ost-Österreich weil ich in Graz (Steiermark) geboren bin und dort die ersten 30 Jahre meines Lebens verbracht habe, und seit 20 Jahren im Wien lebe.

**schiffen**
Ein Zusammenhang mit »Stuhlgang haben« ist mir völlig unbekannt. Dafür wird hierzulande das Verb »*scheißen*« verwendet. (Mehr darüber weiter unten)

Sehr wohl kenne ich aber:

> Es schifft. = Es regnet. (Um auszudrücken, dass man keine Freude mit dem Regen hat)
>   Ich muss schiffen. = Ich muss urinieren.

**Andere im Osten Österreichs gebräuchliche Begriffe für »urinieren«**

- **pinkeln**. Nicht ganz so sachlich-korrekt wie *urinieren*, gilt aber dennoch als gesittet.
- **Wasser lassen**. Wer das in Österreich sagt, läuft Gefahr als verklemmt angesehen zu werden.
- **wohin gehen**. »Entschuldigt mich mal kurz, ich muss mal wohin.« Das ist eigentlich die gängigste Art über das Bedürfnis, die Blase zu entleeren, zu sprechen.
- **pissen**. In Österreich eher selten zu hören, wirkt derb.
- **schiffen**. derb.
- **brunzen**. Sehr derb, bäuerlich.
- **soach’n**. Nur im Dialekt, extrem derb.

War zwar nicht gefragt, aber ergänzt das Thema:
**Andere im Osten Österreichs gebräuchliche Begriffe für »Stuhlgang haben«**

- **scheißen**. Gängigstes Wort.
- **kacken**. Das Wort ist hier zwar bekannt, wird aber kaum verwendet, weil es zu deutsch (also zu wenig österreichisch) klingt.
- **gacksen**. Der Österreich-Ersatz für »kacken«. Fällt aber eher in die Kinder-Sprache

Comment: +1 für die ausführliche Antwort. Die hier beschriebenen Ausdrücke gelten auch für Oberösterreich (studiere da) & Salzburg (komme aus Salzburg)

Answer (score 3):

Ich komme aus dem Rheinland und kenne es als:

> Wasser lassen

bzw.

> Pissen gehen(*ugs., unhöflich*)

Answer (score 1):

In der Schweiz ist ganz anderes...
Umgangssprache: "Im Schiff gehen" oder " etwas ist im Schiff gegangen"
bedeutet das etwas ist nicht geklappt oder nicht funktioniert...
Grüessli Zäme

Answer (score -1):

Mannheim, Rhein-Neckar, Rheinland Pfalz:
Ich habe bis zu diesem Post noch nie etwas von der  Bedeutung 'pinkeln' für 'schiffen' gehört. 
Bei uns war es immer ein Synonym für das große Geschäft. Ich denke auch es handelt sich um ein Generationen Ding, Millennials und danach kennen es wahrscheinlich eher als scheissen.

Schiffen ist weniger derb als kacken oder scheissen.